# iOS interpreting dates with no timezone as being UTC

Tags: c#, ios, datetime, json.net

I'm using a database that doesn't appear to store any timezone information when dates are saved. When running through a C# (Newtonsoft) JSON serializer and used in our javascript based web site, iOS computers reads the date as it being UTC while non-iOS computers read it as the timezone I'm in (i.e. if it's saved as 2020-08-19 00:00:00 in the database, iOS reads it as being 5pm, August 18th). Is there a way in JsonSerializerSettings to set it so that both operating systems will read it the same?

Comment: 1) What does the generated JSON look like?  Can you share a [mcve] showing how the JSON is generated, and parsed? 2) You wrote, *non-iOS computers read it as the timezone I'm in* you mean the timezone the server is in, or the client?

Comment: I don't know if this is helpful, but if you have a `DateTime` object with no timezone specified, you can create a new one with UTC by doing: `var utcDate = DateTime.SpecifyKind(otherDate, DateTimeKind.Utc);`

Comment: 2020-08-19 00:00:00 is how the date looks in the database, 2020-08-19T00:00:00 is how it looks after serialization in the JSON, `{Date: "2020-08-19T00:00:00"}` (no time zone specified here). The settings we are currently using are DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat and DateTimeZoneHandling.RoundtripKind and I mean the time zone the client is in I believe as I think we already had that come up and dealt with it.